# android:layout_gravity will put child view in center vertically but not horizontally

Tags: android, layout

The layout XML is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/translucenter_dark" >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    >
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    ></ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the final layout is :

[image]

Why the progressBar was not put in center both vertically and horizontally. Is it a feature or a bug :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could give the linear layout enclosing the progress bar `android:gravity="center"`.
This will make the progress bar centered.

It seems progress bar utilizes the [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). This class does not support layout_gravity such as [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html). So you will require to use the gravity property of the parent linear layout. This is a pretty good explanation of [gravity](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) in android.

Comment: yes. I understand that works. What i am trying to understand is why layout_gravity does not work.

Comment: +1 for the update. However, Replacing the ProgressBar with a TextView, the Layout_gravity won't center horizontally either.

Comment: Well textview also utilizes ViewGroup.LayoutParams. layout_gravity will center horizontal if your parent linear layout has orientation as vertical. The link i gave you is the best explanation ive found so far.